# Как использовать User Long Poll API ВКонтакте на Python?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, pythonanywhere

Недавно сделал бота для ВКонтакте на Long Poll api(взял готовый скрипт из GitHub'a и переделал его под себя). Скрипт запускается пока что только через командную строку: 'python dir/bot.py'. Однако это не самое лучшее решение и мне захотелось найти бесплатный хостинг с поддержкой Python. Нашёл один pythonanywhere(если знаете хостинг получше, то сообщите), но я не знаю как его настроить. Что нужно сначала сделать? Я примерно понял, как это делается, но как реализовать это на Python вообще не знаю.

Comment: Рассказали историю... но вопроса так и не понял. Отделите вопрос и сделайте его полным распространённым предложением.

Comment: @EugeneDennis вопросы: 'Как подключить LongPoll на хостинге?' и 'Как вообще использовать LongPoll?'

Comment: как использовать описано в описании библиотеки, вы хотя бы ссылку дали, пример там, на хостинге скорей всего нужно поставить через pip "либу" и запихать скрипт-сервис в cron... лучше всего задавайте вопрос про конкретную проблему "как запустить в крон py-файл" "как установить на линукс библиотеку" и т.п.